# How to Convert String to LocalDateTime?

Tags: java

I have a string "2015-09-17T12:00". How can I convert this String to LocalDateTime in format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" and then convert it back to String?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: How do I get rid of that "T" in the String.

Comment: Doesn't the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) handle this?

Comment: Thanks, that works. :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Replace T with whitespace(s):

```
String str="2015-09-17T12:00";
str.replace("T"," ");
```

afterwards convert to **Date** using **SimpleDateFormat**;

Answer (score 0):

We can go with DateTimeFormatter, its thread safety.
Refer to below url:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

sample program on converting String to Local Date Time

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-18-04 T 18:51", formatter);
```

Local Date time provides lot of method to get the hours or minutes or seconds
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html